# How to provide a user to access only a particular bucket in AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-iam

I have a list of buckets in AWS S3. I have created an IAM user. I have an option to provide S3 full or read only access for a user using groups. Is there any options to provide access only to a particular bucket?

Comment: Not sure about that. But, the other way round can definitely happen. I mean, a bucket accepting requests from only a particular user. Wouldn't that work for you?

Comment: @Dawny33 I that case I need to create an IAM user with user name and password. Then I have to provide s3 bucket access for that user. Then that user has to create a key for accessing. Instead, I need to create a programmatic access user (which creates access keys for the user instead of username and password). I'm not able to provide permissions for such an IAM user.

Comment: Related: [Restrict List of Buckets for a Specific User](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17736048/55075).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Amazon's IAM roles generally grant a role access to a particular ARN (Amazon Resource Name). Amazon notes [on their pages](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-arn-format.html) that for S3 a resource

> ...can be a bucket-name or a bucket-name/object-key.

[They also provide a helpful example for doing just this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-how-to-grant-access-to-an-amazon-s3-bucket/) which appears as follows:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::test"]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:DeleteObject"
      ],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::test/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Attach below policy to that user:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                        "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                        "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
                      ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR-BUCKET",
                "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR-BUCKET/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

https://www.serverkaka.com/2018/05/grant-access-to-only-one-s3-bucket-to-aws-user.html

Answer (score 1):

To provide access for specific bucket, you can define the following policy for that user or group:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:DeleteObjectVersion",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutObjectVersionAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        }
    ]
}
```

<sup>Where `my-bucket` is your name of your bucket.</sup>

Then send them the Console URL for that bucket, e.g.

- `https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/BUCKET_NAME/`

Related:

- [Is there an S3 policy for limiting access to only see/access one bucket?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6615168/55075)

Comment: May worth noting your actual policy block actions on the bucket itself and allow control only to inner objects of the bucket.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking for programmatic role creation you might consider [IAM Roles for EC2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html). Those can be applied to EC2 instances without human intervention, and they also avoid the need to store many credentials/keys, which is always nice when using automation.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following policy if you want to access from FTP software like **WinSCP**, **CyberDuck**, etc.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetBucketLocation",
        "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
      "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::test1",
            "arn:aws:s3:::test2"
        ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:DeleteObject"
      ],
      "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::test1/*",
            "arn:aws:s3:::test2/*"
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I learnt from [Writing IAM Policies: How to Grant Access to an Amazon S3 Bucket](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-how-to-grant-access-to-an-amazon-s3-bucket/)